# Struct Byte size calulation

Tags: memory, size, byte, autoit

I'm having trouble figuring out how struct sizes are calculated.

Why are 2 of these structs 8 bytes (I was expecting one to be 6 bytes)

If it is assigned in 4 byte blocks, why is the first struct only 2 bytes?

```
2 : DllStructGetSize(DllStructCreate("word")

4 : DllStructGetSize(DllStructCreate("float"))

8 : DllStructGetSize(DllStructCreate("float;word"))

8 : DllStructGetSize(DllStructCreate("float;word;word"))

12 : DllStructGetSize(DllStructCreate("float;word;word;float"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoIt allocates structures in a way that will make it compatible with C dlls. I don't know the exact details of what that actually is, but there are things like alignment and padding that cause the results you are seeing. As an example, run this C++ code and you get a result of 8:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    float a; 
    char b;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    std::cout << sizeof(foo) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Your best bet if you want to understand this is look at C structure and memory packing. I haven't look into it for a while but try [this](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/).